# Automate downloading of files in a batch

Tags: batch-file, download

Need a help here. 
I have a requirement wherein I have to automate the data retrieving feature of an website. The site has a limitation to search only 30 records at a time. So, what we want to do is login to the site, upload an excel containing 300+ records and click a search button.. and the site should automatically search the records and download the data in excel in a batch of 30.
I wanted to know, if this can be done only using .net or java, without using any automation tool(like selenium etc).If not, what will the best approach to solve it?
Any insight will be helpful.

Comment: If you know what the website requires then all MS languages can do it. See XMLHTTP object in Windows COM interface for a high level interface that any MS language can use. Wininet can do low level calls. You can automate IE in any MS language. IE can also show you the HTTP calls so you know what data to send (F12 in IE).

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and assign the appropriate tags.  This is definitely not a `batch-file` question. Regardless of that, your question is off topic for StackOverFlow as your question is not directly related to any code you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot use .net or Java if you don't have access to the APIs**

( You may try with web API using Rest Client. )

Your requirement can be approached using RPA tools.

I recommend [UIPath](https://www.uipath.com/studio) Studio quick to learn and use